implement the Gaussian Hypergeometric Function 2F1(a, b, c, z) in C#, with the ability on handling negative and large z values
How can I implement the Gaussian Hypergeometric Function 2F1(a, b, c, z) in C#, with the ability on handling negative and large z values?
2F1 is part of the integral of a certain equation resulting in the following implementation:
internal static double HCWR(double distance, double n)
{
    double geometricResult = 2F1(1, 1 / n, 1 + 1 / n, -Math.Pow(distance, -n));
    return (Math.Pow(distance, -n) * geometricResult);
}

n can be any number bigger or equal to 0 and distance can be any number in the interval (0,1].
Values like a = 1, b = 0.5, c = 1.5 and z = -25.0, which should be 0.27468, aren't handled well in every implementation. CenterSpace refuses every |z| > 1 and MathNet.Numerics returns -infinity, while I prefer an implementation that can handle non-integer values for z.

Small z: Direct summation of the series.
Large z: Use transformations such as the analytic continuation of the function.
Negative z: Apply transformations that map negative z to positive values for convergence.

@Alander : If it answered the question you should post it as an answer, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.

I agree with Peter O. I would like to mark that as the correct answer @Alander

What's your question?

Jochla, looks like maybe you have something working, that's great. But bear in mind that numerical evaluation of special functions is pretty difficult in general -- it's a lot of work to cover all the corner cases. If you need the value of an integral for which the exact result contains 2F1, consider just approximating the integral directly, via quadpack or something like that.

I didnt have code so i thought i was simply giving suggestions

Credit to Alander for the comment.
Since in my example the domain n≥0 and distance∈(0,1] is applied, it follows that for
z=-(distance^(-n)) we have z≤−1.
Thus, 0<z/(z−1)<1 holds. We can apply the transformation
2F1(a,b,c,z) = (1-z)^(-a) * 2F1(a, c-b, c, z/(z-1))
and implement the function in this domain as follows:
internal static double HCWR(double distance, double n)
{
    double z = -Math.Pow(distance, -n);
    double c = 1 + 1 / n;
    double b = 1 / n;
    double a = 1;

    double factorTransformed = Math.Pow(1 - z, -a);
    double bTransformed = c - b;
    double zTransformed = z / (z - 1);

    double geometricResult = factorTransformed * CenterSpace.NMath.Core.SpecialFunctions.Hypergeometric2F1(a, bTransformed, c, zTransformed);

    return (Math.Pow(distance, -n) * geometricResult);
}

resulting in the following final implementation:
internal static double HCWR(double distance, double n)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    double c = 1 + 1 / n;
    double z = 1 / (1 + Math.Pow(distance, n));
    return z * CenterSpace.NMath.Core.SpecialFunctions.Hypergeometric2F1(a, b, c, z);
}


Glad my suggestion helped!
